# CSS dependent on ActiveX?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, css

I've got my page working in FF, Chrome, Safari, and even IE8... as long as ActiveX is enabled.

[link removed]

To get the CSS3 features (rotation, opacity, text-shadow) working in IE8, I had to use ActiveX filters.  My problem with this is that when you first go to the site, it pops up with a banner at the top, which users have to click, then click Allow, then click OK.  I don't think most IE users are going to do this.

So I'd like to make the default layout in IE8 (before ActiveX) look decent by moving the header (my name) down and giving it a solid-color background.  However if I add these styles, it makes the page look bad if the user DOES enable ActiveX.

I can't seem to think of a CSS workaround for this, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
Jeff

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not trying to get rotation, opactiy, etc. working in IE8 without filters.  See response to Olafur for clarification...

Comment: Haha, I would almost vote +1 for '... and even IE8'

Comment: The text rotation in FF 3.6 looks awful -- no AA. Unless it's for something dynamic, perhaps better to use an image without jaggies (perhaps just server-side generated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, the good news:

> My problem with this is that when you first go to the site, it pops up with a banner at the top, which users have to click, then click Allow, then click OK. I don't think most IE users are going to do this.

Most IE users won't have to do this, because in the default security settings for ['Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins'](http://surfthenetsafely.com/ieseczone8.htm) is 'Enabled'.  I suspect you are seeing it because either you or your network administrator has purposely locked down ActiveX on your installation.

Now the bad news - I'm not sure there's going to be any way to test for ActiveX without triggering the warning message for people who haven't got it enabled by default.  However, if you can work out a reliable test for it (don't know how exactly, but some variation of [applying a filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx) then checking to see if it applied should work), applying the styles ought to be relatively easy with a bit of JavaScript.

Declare your default rules for your page without any rotation, opacity or text shadow in the normal way:

```
h1 {...}
p {...}
```

On page load run your routine to detect whether ActiveX is supported, if it is dynamically add a class to the body element such as `ax-en`.  Meanwhile in your stylesheet you have rules like this:

```
.ax-en h1 { /* -ms-filter stuff and associated rules */ }
.ax-en p { /* -ms-filter stuff and associated rules */ }
```

This is basically the approach used by [modernizr.js](http://www.modernizr.com/), have a read of [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/) for a longer explanation of the general strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Those are ActiveX only filters and I don't think there are any available that can do the same effect via CSS.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear...  I realize that I can't do rotate and opacity without ActiveX filters.  So what I'd like to do is have the header be a solid color, unrotated for IE8 users unless they click to allow ActiveX. I can achieve this by just putting "background-color: rgb(whatever)", but then if the user clicks Allow ActiveX, the ActiveX opacity filter won't override the rgb().  I'm having similar problems with the positioning of the header.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation, opacity and text shadow: No, you can't do it. You have to use a CSS `filter` declaration that uses ActiveX in IE8.

However for other features - border shadow, border radius, etc, I'd suggest you look into [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which does allow you to support a number of modern browser features in CSS within IE (even in the ever hated IE6).

You will be able to do all these features in standard CSS when IE9 is released, but that won't be for some time yet, and you'll still have to deal with IE8 (and IE6 and IE7) for some time to come, even when IE9 is released.