# Why don't IE hacks work for me?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with dropshadow and other hacks in IE.  I have seen lots and lots of the fixes for IE.  I cannot get them to work for me and I cannot find an explanation of why.

Here is an example of one of the hacks I have tried:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR6ZU.png

My code and webpage are on the left. The website this hack is taken from is:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

What really gets me is that it will work on that site in IE.  I also have the source inspected (in chrome) but the page is displayed in IE.

This is IE 8, just to clarify.

Any explanation of this would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shadow">Nothing to see, move along.</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

.shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
box-shadow:3px 3px 4px #000;



-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";


filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');

background-color:00ccff;
}

Comment: I think you should put the code that's not working in your post, not as an image. I think this is why you have a downvote. Click [edit] and add your code, and note the code formatting tools. Leave the image link though, as it is quite relevant.

Comment: You should use a local web server to avoid certain problems, including this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely caused by not setting the correct DOCTYPE. Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your document

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have not accepted the *security risk* alert at the top of the browser, since the "hacks" are implemented in ActiveX.

Also, see [CSS dependent on ActiveX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119364/css-dependent-on-activex)